# Is it safe for smart contracts to handle secrets?

Tags: solidity, security, evm

Is the runtime environment of a smart contract going to be seen by the hosting node? If not, how?

Can the smart contract safely pass an API key to memory?

Should Solidity developers just deem smart contracts runtime as endangered similarly to web apps front ends?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a public blockchain, so anyone can read any of the data stored in the blockchain. This includes the compiled bytecode of smart contracts as well as anything they store.

Yes, you should consider it as public as web app front ends.